# Letra ñ genera (arg: 1) en terminal Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, teclado

Estoy utilizando la distribución Kali Rolling de Linux.

Accidentalmente moví algo en el editor nano y ahora cada vez que presiono la letra **ñ** en la terminal aparece `(arg: 1)` como si presionara <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>.

Tambien dentro de nano el caracter **ñ** genera espacios vacíos.

Intenté cambiar de distribución de teclado, reiniciar el computador, reconfigurar el paquete controlador del teclado pero el problema persiste, no quiero tener que formatear el pc por este problema

¿Alguien tiene una idea de cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: Tendra que ver con la distribucion del teclado? (distribucion - idioma, no se bien como se llama)

Comment: @LcsGrz lo dudo, intenté con varias distribuciones en español y el problema persiste en todas, con una distribución en inglés no hay problema porque la  ñ se reemplaza con un ;

Comment: MMMM, no sabria mas que decirte eso, disculpa

Answer (score 0):

A mí ese comportamiento me ocurrió a raíz de que algún paquete escribiese:

```
export LANG=en_USexport PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"
```

en mi fichero `.bash_profile`.

Si lo comentas, la ñ volverá a funcionarte

Answer (score 0):

Lo descrito me ha pasado con la nueva instalación de ARMBIAN en mi Banana Pi M2 ZERO, y con la ayuda del anterior post y lo que he encontrado por la web, lo he solucionado con lo siguiente:

Cuando nos pasa lo de teclear la [ñ] y nos aparece el (arg: 1), pues primero vamos a comprobar el idioma con "locale", y si nos aparece LANG= "POSIX" aun habiendo regenerado nuestro idioma, recomiendo ejecutar lo siguiente:

- Primero; actualizar y aplicar posibles cambios:

```bash
sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get upgrade;sudo apt-get install;sudo reboot
```

- Segundo; limpiar los idiomas y volver a generar el "es_ES.UTF-8":

```bash
sudo apt-get purge locales;sudo apt-get install locales;export LANGUAGE=es_ES.UTF-8;export LANG=es_ES.UTF-8;sudo locale-gen es_ES.UTF-8;sudo localectl set-locale es_ES.UTF-8
```

Y si anteriormente ya teníamos nuestro teclado bien configurado (sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration) ya nos tiene que aparecer la ñ cuando le damos a su tecla.

Hacer un reboot para comprobar que los cambios han quedado grabados, y revisar con los comandos:

"locale" y "localectl status" nos tiene que aparecer nuestra configuración como "es_ES.UTF-8"